# Evaluate these infinite products $\prod_{n\geq 2}(1-\frac{1}{n^3})$ and $\prod_{n\geq 1}(1+\frac{1}{n^3})$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, infinite-product

What is

1. $\prod\limits_{n\geq 2}(1-\frac{1}{n^3})=?$
2. $\prod\limits_{n\geq 1}(1+\frac{1}{n^3})=?$

I am sure about their convergence. But don't know about exact values. Know some bounds as well. For example first one is in interval (2/3,1) and second one is in (2,3).

Comment: What is $s$ here ?

Comment: What does this have to do with zeta-functions? Those are generally products over primes, not over all $n$.

Comment: @DiffeoR : not sure..

Comment: @Gerry Myerson : may be something to do with multi zeta values?? not sure..

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: If you find a connection to zeta-functions, you can edit them back into the tags.

Comment: @Did : I am sure about their convergence. But don't know about exact values. Know some bounds as well. For example first one is in interval (2/3,1) and second one is in (2,3).

Comment: @Biswa, It looked like $s$. I'm deleting my comment then.

Comment: According to Maple the second value is 
$$\frac{\cosh(\frac{1}{2}\pi \sqrt{3})}{\pi} \approx 2.4282\dots$$ and the first is one third of the second.

Comment: @gammatester : Will you please explain how did you get that expression involving cosh?

Comment: With the Maple command `b:=product(1+1/n^3, n=1..infinity);` you get a first result 
$$b = \frac{\sin(\pi(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} i \sqrt{3}))}{\pi}\cdot$$
And because the result is real a second command `Re(b)` gives the expression for the second product:
$$\frac{\cosh(\frac{1}{2} \pi \sqrt{3}))}{\pi}$$
Note that Wolfram Alpha gives the $\cosh$ result in one step.

Comment: @Biswa cf. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteProduct.html formulae (20), (22) and (30). There is also a reference to a general formula.

Comment: The first question was asked (and answered) here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319784/evaluating-prod-limits-n-2-infty-left1-frac1n3-right

Answer (score 8):

- **Ramanujan** has [already answered](http://www.imsc.res.in/~rao/ramanujan/collectedpapers/question/q261.htm) these two questions $100$ years ago!

  ---
- The same questions have already been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673495/prod-i-1-infty1-fracki3-for-integer-k), by **Mhenni Benghorbal**, and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674615/how-find-this-prod-n-2-infty-left1-frac1n6-right), by **Claude Leibovici**.

  ---
- Generally speaking, $\quad\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^\infty\bigg(1\pm\frac{x^{2k+1}}{n^{2k+1}}\bigg)=\pm\frac1{x^{2k+1}\cdot\displaystyle\prod_{j=1}^{2k+1}\Gamma\bigg((\pm1)^{^{\frac j{2k+1}}}x\bigg)}$ . When $x=1$ and the sign is negative, in order to find the value of your product, you must obviously divide through $1-\bigg(\dfrac xn\bigg)^{2k+1}$ But since both the numerator and denominator are $0$, we must use [l'Hopital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'Hopital's_rule). For $k=1\iff2k+1=3$, this will lead you to the above-linked results, which have also been confirmed by **Gamma Tester** in this post's comment section.

  ---
- As far as the relationship to the $\zeta(3)$ function is concerned, this is clear from Euler's approach to the [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem), which connects $\zeta(2)$ with the infinite product for $\dfrac{\sin x}x$ , as well as from [the fact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria) that, in general, the convergence of $\prod(1+a_k)$ is the same as that of $\sum a_k$. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Just one quick observation.

Let, $P_1$ denotes the first product and $P_2$ the second. Then,
since $P_1$ converges and is positive, $$\log{P_1}=\sum_{n\ge 2}\log\left(1-\frac 1{n^3}\right)=-\sum_{n\ge 2}\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{kn^{3k}}=-\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{\zeta(3k)-1}{k}$$

Similarly, $$\log P_2=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}\zeta(3k)}{k}$$