# How can I evaluate the following Gamma Function value

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, gamma-function

Over the last few days, I have been studying equation (20) in the following (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteProduct.html)

A special case of this formula is given as follows

$$ \prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n^3}\right)= \frac{\cosh(\frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt3)}{3\pi} $$

where the RHS is $$ \frac{1}{3\cdot \Gamma(\sqrt[3]{-1})\cdot \Gamma(-\sqrt[3]{-1}^2)}$$

As I proceed to plug these gamma functions into WolframAlpha, it gives me approximations and integrals as if these did not have an exact value or it was not known.

So my question is how can I go about solving these?

I tried looking at the gamma reflection formula but no cigar.

Thank you very much for your help and time.

Comment: Looks like a case where you basically plug $(-1)^{1/3}$ into the Euler Relection Formula. Recall the relationship between $\cos$ and $\cosh.$ Alternatively, calculate the Hadamard Product for $\cosh z$

Comment: Specifically, take the standard reflection formula and substitute $z \to \tfrac 12 - z$ to find $$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-z\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+z\right)=\frac{\pi}{\cos(\pi z)}$$ From which your identity is immediate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding a particular evaluation of $\prod\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319784/understanding-a-particular-evaluation-of-prod-limits-n-2-infty-left1-fr)